# Hibernate setMaxResults() not working for Sybase database query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, sap-ase

Either of the following two approaches to executing a simple Hibernate query with limited results do not work in Sybase. They both result in a **SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.**

```
Query q = session.createQuery( "from Record" );
q.setMaxResults( 50 );
q.list();
```

or

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria( Record.class );
criteria.setMaxResults( 50 );
criteria.list();
```

It appears the actual SQL generated in both of these cases looks like...

```
select top ? record_id, etc...
```

and Sybase is balking at the ?, which Hibernate is not filling in with the value 50 (this is my guess). I've searched everywhere and while others have encountered a similar error, it was not due to attempting to limit the results.

I can execute a direct SQL statement such as 'select top 50 from Record' and it works perfectly, so I know my version of Sybase supports the syntax.

I'm using Hibernate 3.2 and Sybase ASE 15.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you configured Hibernate to use a wrong SQL dialect.

It looks like `HSQLDialect` is the only dialect that can produce `limit ? ?`, and it's definitely a wrong choice for Sybase.

**See also:**

- [3.4.1. SQL Dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects)

Comment: How embarrassing. You are exactly right. We were using HSQLDialect. Someone else set up the hibernate.cfg.xml file so I always just assumed it was right. We've been working around not being able to do limits in our project for years now. Thank you so much. It works beautifully now that we're using the SybaseDialect.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `setFirstResult(1)`  as well like:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Record.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(1);
criteria.setMaxResults(50);
criteria.list();
```

Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, same error. I'd imagine others have found this issue, but I can't find anyone else complaining.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I do exactly as you asked above, Hibernate turns that in SQL that looks like:
select limit ? ? record_id, etc
Which I know does NOT work in Sybase. Only the 'top 50' syntax is supported, from what I understand. But, the error I get is still the same because I think it's complaining about the '?' which it interprets as @p0 which is some internal Hibernate variable, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxResults()` is typically used together with `setFirstResult()` to implement paging. Eg. the first query returns records 1 to 1000, the second query returns 1001 to 2000, and so on. Try using together.

`setFetchSize()` control how many rows are fetched at a time by the JDBC driver.(if implemented)  So, if you for example have setMaxResults(1000) and setFetchSize(100) the query will return no more than 1000 rows, and will do so in batches of 100 rows at a time.

Comment: I appreciate the info. I am familiar with how to use the methods. All I'm interested in is solving this easily reproducible issue. I'll deal with paging and incremental fetching later. I tried to use these methods along with setMaxResults and I continue to get the same issue.

Comment: that "?" is coming from the prepared statement as you already know. It should be putting the number 50 there, before executing the sql. Maybe the jdbc driver you are using has some problems/bugs?

Comment: Not an issue with the JDBC driver because I can use the same driver to execute the simple sql 'select top 50 * from build_records' and it works fine. The issue seems to be Hibernate not putting the number 50 into the SQL when it generates it. Can't imagine this would have gone unrecognized except for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use createSQLQuery option which works with TOP.